# Remove the left scroll bar html

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an html code that would remove the scroll bar on the left (Y axis scroll bar) Like when you resize a page that scroll bar doesn't come up also with the bottom scroll bar as well? Thanks.

Btw, an example is google. Resize the page on google and you'll see what im talking about

Comment: google.com doesn't have a LEFT scroll bar in any window size in any browsers i know - it's really unclear what are you talking about

Comment: [overflow-y:hidden;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-y).

Comment: Are you on a RTL-page? My y-axis scrollbars are on the right side.

Comment: if u think that answer works then u should accept it by click the right sign near the answer. hope u mind

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the scrollbar disappear, one way would be to code you site so that it has a fluid layout and it would adjust to browser window resizing (no fixed width blocks, for example, or floated content that would reorder upon resizing.)

Of course, the simplest way is to set `overflow: hidden;` in CSS to the block you need to remove the scrollbar from, however, that would just obscure the content that is out of viewport.

**More about fluid layouts**

These are literally some of the first links I got when googling for it:

- http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/
- http://24ways.org/2006/intricate-fluid-layouts/

You can even find ready-made layouts if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

May be this code will help you, add this code in head section

```
   <style type="text/css">
    body {
           /* use any one, according to the requirment */
        overflow:hidden;  /* for x & y scroll bar */
        overflow-x:hidden; /* for x scroll bar */
        overflow-y:hidden;/* for y scroll bar */
    }
    </style>
```